# Определить количество восклицательных знаков входящих в четные строки

Tags: pascal, файловая-система, файлы, текст

Помогите пожалуйста!)

в текстовом файле "T" определить количество восклицательных знаков входящих в четные строки. вывести на печать строки в которых этих знаков больше чем 2.
Вот мой вариант, но PascalABC пишет  Ошибка времени выполнения: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Файл 'E:\in.txt' не найден.  Что делать?

```
program new;
uses crt;
var f: text;
    s: string;
    i,k,ns: integer;
begin
    assign(f,'E:\in.txt');
    reset(f);
    writeln('Количество "!" в четных строках:');
    while not (eof(f)) do
          begin
          inc(ns);
          readln(f,s);
          if ns mod 2=0 then
             begin
               k:=0;
               for i:=1 to length(s) do
                   if s[i]='!' then inc(k);
               writeln(ns,' строка - ',k);
             end;
          end;
    reset(f);
    writeln('Четные строки, в которых количество "!" больше 2:');
    while not (eof(f)) do
          begin
          inc(ns);
          readln(f,s);
          if ns mod 2=0 then
             begin
             k:=0;
             for i:=1 to length(s) do
                 if s[i]='!' then inc(k);
             if k>2 then writeln(s);
             end;
          end;
    close(f);
    readln;
end.
```

Comment: >но PascalABC пишет Ошибка времени выполнения: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Файл 'E:\in.txt' не найден. Что делать?

поместить файл по адресу **E:\in.txt**.  С уважением, ваш кэп

Comment: Мой файл там и находиться Та же ошибка выскакивает